# AngularJS limitTo withvalue from model (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, limits

my model loads his data from a json file.

```
{
    "soonepisodes":{
        "limit":"3",
        "oderby":"percent"
    },
    "featuredreview":"1",
    "newsticker":{
        "limit":5
    }
}
```

A second json is loaded:

```
[
    {"id":"1","project":"Tokyo Ghoul","episode":"03","percent":"70","current":"QC","planned":"01.01.2015"},
    {"id":"2","project":"Tokyo Ghoul","episode":"03","percent":"50","current":"QC","planned":"01.01.2015"},
    {"id":"3","project":"Tokyo Ghoul","episode":"03","percent":"40","current":"QC","planned":"01.01.2015"},
    {"id":"4","project":"Tokyo Ghoul","episode":"03","percent":"30","current":"QC","planned":"01.01.2015"},
    {"id":"5","project":"Tokyo Ghoul","episode":"03","percent":"10","current":"QC","planned":"01.01.2015"}
]
```

The first is for some settings, e.g. how to order the informations from second json and how many results show be displayed at once.

My template is this:

```
<div id="releases-soon">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="release in feed.releases | orderBy:'feed.soonepisodes.oderby' | limitTo:3 ">
            {{release.percent}}<!-- | orderBy:'feed.soonepisodes.oderby' 'feed.soonepisodes.limit'-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

First i want to order in given direction - this works fine by my variable name. (feed is my alias in this model)
Now i want to use - insted of this hardcoded form of limit - the variable from my controller -> feed.soonepisodes.limit

I tried the expression with single quotes, without, with quotes in jason and without in json to limit the view to the given value in my json, but i never see anything (like limitTo:0)

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap your `orderBy` parameters in quotes.

Replace:

```
orderBy:'feed.soonepisodes.oderby'
```

With:

```
orderBy:feed.soonepisodes.oderby
```

Comment: that was not the question - im asking about the limitTo-filter

Comment: __[That limit should work just fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/sIULoHTlQYUukBs7anEV?p=preview)__